# Can Agora SDK can be used to create a real time ML integrated video call

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, agora.io

I want to create a video calling app which also analyze the video and create subtitle to video based on video with translations to preferred language. Can I use Agora SDK for it? And how could machine learning can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Technically you can use any RTC SDKs for ML. Problems are how many lines of code you have to write, how tricky it is to do. Things also matter like what the programming language you have to learn, which platform you have to choose, etc.

As most ML engineers choose Python as their first choice as Python is really easy to learn and use. Agora released cross-platform Python SDKs and demos for ML community recently:

- [Agora-Python-SDK](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Python-SDK)
- [Agora-Python-Tensorflow-Demo](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Python-Tensorflow-Demo)

The demo works pretty well.

One drawback is the Agora Python SDK does not support a sub-set of the Main Agora SDK API currently, maybe full support will come soon.